# how to define this in grpc proto file for json [ { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo" } ]

Tags: grpc, proto

I need to expose a GRPC service endpoint with json format as shown in the following code block, how to define my proto file to match this format ?

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/status",
        "value": "AVAILABLE"
    }
]
```

Currently I am only able to match it to this

```
{
    "ops": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/photoUrl",
            "value": "https://www.bigcats.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, gRPC is done to return your second output. Since your proto file is something like:

```
rpc GetOps (Empty) returns (Ops) {}

message Ops {
    repeated Op ops = 1;
}
message Op {
   string op = 1;
   string path = 2;
   string value = 3;
}
```

You are telling gRPC there is a list of `Op` called `ops`, this is why you have to add the `ops` field.

By the way, as a workaround, you can return an stream and create the array in the client:

```
rpc GetStreamOps (Empty) returns (stream Op) {}

message Op {
   string op = 1;
   string path = 2;
   string value = 3;
}
```

The server returns the differents objects and the client create the array. Also, I think is a better way return the value and get the `response.ops`